Model works well on input from microphone but terribly after it's streamed from websockets
I am building a voice-enabled assistant on the web. I am following this tutorial using Huggingface and Python. It uses the system microphone as the audio source, but I am using the microphone using the MediaDevices web interface and shipping buffers of audio data to a WebSockets endpoint.
The Problem: while the classification part of the above tutorial works, the automatic speech recognition is garbled compared to running the demo just on a Python process directly using the same parameters.
For example, if I say: "Hey Marvin, please transcribe my speech," I get exactly that if I run the code using the Python microphone input as in the Huggingface example, but if I run it via the Websockets -> Python backend -> Huggingface setup, I get "Hey Marvin, Please Please transcribe my 5 my speech."
I am a bit lost as to why this is happening. I copied all the striding and ffmpeg logic that the Huggingface audio microphone library uses on the microphone audio, and it's quite a lot of code, so I'm summarizing here:

First, the stream of audio buffers from the client goes through an ffmpeg process. Here's the process definition:

async def ffmpeg_process(sampling_rate=16000):
    ar = f"{sampling_rate}"
    ac = "1"
    format_for_conversion = "f32le"
    ffmpeg_command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-i", "pipe:0",
        "-ac", ac,
        "-acodec", f"pcm_{format_for_conversion}",
        "-ar", ar,
        "-f", format_for_conversion,
        "pipe:1"]
    return await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        *ffmpeg_command,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )


Then, the output goes through a striding process:

async def ffmpeg_generator(ffmpeg_output):
    # code "borrowed" from https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/fb78769b9c053876ed7ae152ee995b0439a4462a/src/transformers/pipelines/audio_utils.py#L98
    chunk_length_s = 1.0
    stream_chunk_s = 0.25
    sampling_rate = 16000
    chunk_s = stream_chunk_s
    dtype = np.float32
    size_of_sample = 4
    stride_length_s = chunk_length_s / 6
    chunk_len = int(round(sampling_rate * chunk_length_s)) * size_of_sample
    if isinstance(stride_length_s, (int, float)):
        stride_length_s = [stride_length_s, stride_length_s]
    stride_left = int(
        round(sampling_rate * stride_length_s[0])) * size_of_sample
    stride_right = int(
        round(sampling_rate * stride_length_s[1])) * size_of_sample
    audio_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=chunk_s)

    async for item in chunk_bytes_iter(ffmpeg_output, chunk_len=chunk_len, stride=(
            stride_left, stride_right), stream=True):
        item["raw"] = np.frombuffer(item["raw"], dtype=dtype)
        item["stride"] = (
            item["stride"][0] // size_of_sample,
            item["stride"][1] // size_of_sample,
        )
        item["sampling_rate"] = sampling_rate
        audio_time += delta
        if datetime.datetime.now() > audio_time + 10 * delta:
            continue
        yield item

async def chunk_bytes_iter(audio_generator: AsyncGenerator[bytes, None], chunk_len: int, stride: Tuple[int, int], stream: bool = False):
    """
    Reads raw bytes from an iterator and does chunks of length `chunk_len`. Optionally adds `stride` to each chunks to
    get overlaps. `stream` is used to return partial results even if a full `chunk_len` is not yet available.
    """
    acc = b""
    stride_left, stride_right = stride
    if stride_left + stride_right >= chunk_len:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Stride needs to be strictly smaller than chunk_len: ({stride_left}, {stride_right}) vs {chunk_len}")
    _stride_left = 0

    async for raw in audio_generator:
        acc += raw
        if stream and len(acc) < chunk_len:
            stride = (_stride_left, 0)
            yield {"raw": acc[:chunk_len], "stride": stride, "partial": True}
        else:
            while len(acc) >= chunk_len:
                # We are flushing the accumulator
                stride = (_stride_left, stride_right)
                item = {"raw": acc[:chunk_len], "stride": stride}
                if stream:
                    item["partial"] = False
                yield item
                _stride_left = stride_left
                acc = acc[chunk_len - stride_left - stride_right:]
    # not sure what to do if there's accumulated sound left?
    # # Last chunk
    if len(acc) > stride_left:
        item = {"raw": acc, "stride": (_stride_left, 0)}
        if stream:
            item["partial"] = False
        yield item

The parameters sampling_rate=16000 and chunk_length_s=1 match the client's configuration for recording the audio.
3. The output is read into the transcriber:
async def process_audio(audio: StreamReader):
        formatted = ffmpeg_stream(audio)

        question = ""
        async for frame in ffmpeg_generator(formatted):
            print(f"Current question: {question}")
            pred = await async_transcriber(frame)
            print(f"Current prediction: {pred}")
            if not pred["partial"][0]:
                question += pred["text"]


It seems that this is directionally close but something is certainly off, any clue if there's something I can optimize to make it work?
